# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bPopup' after first time

Tags: jquery, popup, bpopup

I want to make a dynamic popup with url. For the first time pop up is working fine. But after closing the popup, pop up is not working. I only get the message in console like "**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bPopup'**"

I am using following library: [bPopup](https://github.com/dinbror/bpopup)

Here is my code:

```
    jQuery('.entry-link-pop').bind('click', function(e) {
    var url = jQuery(this).attr('link');
           // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
           // e.preventDefault();

           // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
           jQuery('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({loadUrl: url});
           // return false;
     });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error mostly pops up if you've included jquery.js files twice (not for this necessarily, but from a general point of view). Please ensure that you've **NOT** done that :)

Comment: thanks @passionateCoder
i loaded page once and popup once. i think every file is starting twice. thanks for your information. if you write on answer section, i can choose as answer.

Comment: be sure to upvote the answer if u think it'll help other ppl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error mostly pops up if you've included jquery.js files twice (not for this necessarily, but from a general point of view). Please ensure that you've NOT done that :)